# displaying items on the same line on page

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a header with Logo on the left, Menu with 5 links in the centre and then a log in / Register on the right of the screen so it looks like :-

```
Logo     Menu 1    Menu 2    Menu 3    Menu 4    Menu 5        Log In / Register
```

I can get the Logo and Menu's to sit together but the Log in / Register is on the line below.

I'm using Divs and not tables.

```css
body{
     margin:0%;
     background:#FFC;
     background-size:cover; 
    }

    .header{
     background:#000;
    }

    .logo{
     float:left;
     padding-right:5%;
     margin-left:10%;
     height:100;
    }

    /*basket*/
    .basketTray{
     width:40%;
     color:white;
     padding-top:24;
     padding-bottom:20;
     width:40%;
    }

    /*menu*/
    .menu{
     padding-top:24;
     padding-bottom:20;
     width:40%;
     margin-left:15%;
     }

    .menu li{
     display: inline;
     padding-right: 25px;
     font-size: 1.3em; 
    }

    a{
     text-decoration:none;
     color:white;
    }
```

```html
<header class="header">
     <div class="Logo"><img src="images/logo.jpg" alt="Company Logo" height="100"></div>
        <!--navigation menu-->
   <div class="menu">
      <ol>
                <li><a href="index.php">Home</a> </li>
                <li><a href="bags.php">Bags</a></li>
                <li><a href="boxes.php">Boxes</a></li>
                <li><a href="ingredients.php">Ingredients</a></li>
                <li><a href="login.php">Log In</a></li>
           </ol>
  </div>
        <div class="basketTray">
            Log In| Register
        </div>
    </header>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set `display:inline-block` to the menu and the div with "Log in"

And there was some mistakes in your css, here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nvhuLrua/1/).

```
body{
    margin:0%;
    background:#FFC;
    background-size:cover; 
}

.header{
    background:#000;
}

.Logo{
    float:left;
    width:20%
    padding-right:5%;
}

/*basket*/
.basketTray{
    display:inline-block;
    color:white;
    padding-top:24px;
    padding-bottom:20px;
    width:40%;
}

/*menu*/
.menu{
    padding-top:24;
    padding-bottom:20;
    width:40%;
    display:inline-block;
 }

.menu li{
    display: inline;
    padding-right: 25px;
    font-size: 1.3em;   
}

a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Place the header (no need for a class, is probably a unique element) as a table-cell.

Then place the div's as table-cells:

```
header {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
header>div {
    display: table-cell;
}
header .menu ol li {
    display: inline;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/xg7twqvt/)

Answer (score 0):

```
    `<HTML>
<head>
    <title>The Tao Of Chocolate</title>
<style>

body{
    margin:0%;
    background:#FFC;
    background-size:cover; 
}

.header{
    background:#000;
      height: 103px;
}

.logo{
    float:left;
    padding-right:5%;
    margin-left:10%;
    height:100;
}

/*basket*/
.basketTray{
     /* width: 40%; */
  color: white;
  padding-top: 22px;
  padding-bottom: 20;
  /* width: 40%; */
  float: left;
}

/*menu*/
.menu{
    padding-top:24;
    padding-bottom:20;
    width:40%;
    margin-left:15%;
    float: left;
 }

.menu li{
    display: inline;
    padding-right: 25px;
    font-size: 1.3em;   
}

a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:white;
}
</style>
</head>


<body>
    <header class="header">
    <div class="Logo"><img src="images/logo.jpg" alt="Company Logo" height="100"></div>
    <!--navigation menu-->
    <div class="menu">
        <ol>
            <li><a href="index.php">Home</a> </li>
            <li><a href="bags.php">Bags</a></li>
            <li><a href="boxes.php">Boxes</a></li>
            <li><a href="ingredients.php">Ingredients</a></li>
            <li><a href="login.php">Log In</a></li>
        </ol>
    </div>
    <div class="basketTray">
    <ul>
    <li>
        Log In| Register
   </li>
   </ul>
    </div>
</header>



</html>'

Try this code
```

Answer (score 0):

you just have to work with your css.
Firstly introduce float:left to menu class and basket tray class.
Then introduce a div whose class clears the float property like

```
.clear{
        clear: both;    
    }
```

and do some work with your paddings and widths and your job is done.

```
body{
        margin:0%;
        background:#FFC;
        background-size:cover; 
    }

    .header{
        background:#000;
    }

    .logo{
        float:left;
        height:100;
    }

    /*basket*/
    .basketTray{

        color:white;
        padding-top:24;
        padding-bottom:20;
        float:left;
    }

    /*menu*/
    .menu{
        padding-top:24;
        padding-bottom:20;
        margin-left:15%;
        float:left;
     }

    .menu li{
        display: inline;
        padding-right: 25px;
        font-size: 1.3em;   
    }

    a{
        text-decoration:none;
        color:white;
    }
    .clear{
        clear: both;    
    }


<header class="header">
        <div class="Logo"><img src="images/logo.jpg" alt="Company Logo" height="100"></div>
        <!--navigation menu-->
        <div class="menu">
            <ol>
                <li><a href="index.php">Home</a> </li>
                <li><a href="bags.php">Bags</a></li>
                <li><a href="boxes.php">Boxes</a></li>
                <li><a href="ingredients.php">Ingredients</a></li>
                <li><a href="login.php">Log In</a></li>
            </ol>
        </div>
        <div class="basketTray">
            Log In| Register
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
body{
    margin:0%;
    background:#FFC;
    background-size:cover; 
}

.header{
    background:#000;
    width=100%;
}

.logo img{
    float:left;
   height:80px;
   width:200px;
}

/*basket*/
.basketTray p{
    float:right;

    color:green;

}

.basketTray {
    float:right;

    color:green;

}

/*menu*/
.menu{

    padding:24;

    width:40%;
    margin-left:31%;
 }

.menu li{
    display: inline;
    padding-right: 25px;
    font-size: 1.3em;   
}

a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:white;
}



<header class="header">

    <div class="Logo"><img src="images/logo.jpg" alt="Company Logo" ></div>
      <div class="basketTray">
       <p> Log In| Register</p>
    </div>
    <!--navigation menu-->
    <div class="menu">
        <ol>
            <li><a href="index.php">Home</a> </li>
            <li><a href="bags.php">Bags</a></li>
            <li><a href="boxes.php">Boxes</a></li>
            <li><a href="ingredients.php">Ingredients</a></li>
            <li><a href="login.php">Log In</a></li>
        </ol>
    </div>

</header>
```